# How to implement multiple selection on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, multiple-select

I have an index where I'm showing a list of documents. I would like to implement a multiple select in order to do different actions to the documents the user has selected

I have created a

```
<%= check_box_tag 'id', 'document.id %>
```

for each document, inside a form_tag

But if I select multiple checkboxes, the params that are passed to the action are overwrited and I'm just receiving the id of the last checkbox I've selected in the id param.

¿Anyone knows how to implement multiple select?¿Any other approach?
I'm running  Rails 3 and Ruby 1.8.7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `:multiple => true`

```
<%= check_box_tag 'id', document.id, :multitple => true %>
```

This will give you results in form of an array in `params[:id]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's fast
I've tried what you said but it didn't work. But after reading just a bit I've changed the name of the parameter:
`<%= check_box_tag 'id[]', document.id, :multitple => true %>`
And that works fine

Comment: I've also deleted the
`:multiple => true `
and it still working

Comment: Great it worked out for you. I confused `:multiple` option on `check_box` helper with `check_box_tag` helper. It doesn't works with "_tag" version it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction (plural):

```
<%= check_box_tag 'ids[]', document.id %>
```

ensure your model is properly set for `attr_accessible`  something like `:document_ids`